# Does getAdapterPosition() works with Sdk Version 25?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using Sdk Version 25. I'm trying to use getAdapterPosition() and getLayoutPosition but I'm getting the sintax error "cannot resolve method". Any help please, Im new to Android.

Build gradle module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.seaside.runway"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

EDIT:

This is the list of all my imports:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Locale;
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? Those are methods of `RecyclerView` which you have not included in your dependencies.

Comment: @Pztar I just added and syncrhonized gradle, still having the same error.

Comment: Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Make sure you're importing the right classes.

Comment: @Pztar just edited the question and added the list of all my imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this import in the class where you use your `RecyclerView`

`import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;`